# Print elements containing only 2 strings

Tags: python

I have this list

```
lst = [' SOME TEXT\nSOME TEXT\nFTY = 1', 'A|1\nB|5\nC|3\n \nD|0\nE|0', 'D|4\nE|1\nG|1', '\nblah blah', '\n---    HHGTY', 
    'SOME TEXT\nFTY = 1\nA|3\nB|2\nC|8\nD|6\nE|9\nF|3', '', 'blah blah\n \nblah blah', 
    '---    HHGTY'
    ]
```

and I want to print only the elements containing `|` or `HHGTY`. I using the code below, but is printing
`SOME TEXT` and `FTY = 1` too. What is wrong? Thanks

```
>>> for s in lst:
...     if ("|" in s) or ("HHGTY" in s):
...             print(s)
...
A|1
B|5
C|3

D|0
E|0
D|4
E|1
G|1

---    HHGTY
SOME TEXT
FTY = 1
A|3
B|2
C|8
D|6
E|9
F|3
---    HHGTY
>>>
```

Comment: your code works perfect for me, where's the mistake tho? i replaced the `print(s)` to `print(f's: >"{s}"')` for debugging purposes, and seems like the whole string that has `SOME TEXT` and `FTY = 1` is ` SOME TEXT
FTY = 1
A|3
B|2
C|8
D|6
E|9
F|3 ` which has `|`. So, technically, your code has no errors

Comment: The result is as expected, in `'SOME TEXT\nFTY = 1\nA|3\nB|2\nC|8\nD|6\nE|9\nF|3'` there is a `'|'` so it will print this item which includes `nFTY = 1` part.

Comment: By print elements do you mean elements separated by spaces? Like words?

Comment: `'SOME TEXT\nFTY = 1\nA|3\nB|2\nC|8\nD|6\nE|9\nF|3'` this string fits your `if` condition. `SOME TEXT` and `FTY = 1` are only parts of it, and the whole string is printed.

Comment: All you guys are correct. I saw the issue with your comments. Thank you

Comment: The string `'SOME TEXT\nFTY = 1\nA|3\nB|2\nC|8\nD|6\nE|9\nF|3'` contains `|` yet you say you don't want it reported. So you need to explain *why* you expect it not to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```py
for s in lst:
    for subs in s.split('\n'):
        if ("|" in subs) or ("HHGTY" in subs):
            print(subs)
```

Comment: `s.splitlines():` also does the job.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary Yes, but for me `split()` is shorter and easier to remember, and more powerful. In fact I do not know this method `splitlines()`  exist before you tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your `'SOME TEXT\nFTY = 1\nA|3\nB|2\nC|8\nD|6\nE|9\nF|3'` element `'|'` is present.

Comment: So it checks that | is in s so it evaluates to true and so it is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing everything right:
`SOME TEXT` and `FTY = 1` are parts of `SOME TEXT \ nFTY = 1 \ nA | 3 \ nB | 2 \ nC | 8 \ nD | 6 \ nE | 9 \ nF | 3`.